# Value error: too many values to unpack in a specific example

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

please help with the below script:

table_headers = body_content.find_all('th')[:3]

```
row_number = 2

d1, d2, d3 = body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td')
```

Giving error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `.find_all('td')` does not return exactly 3 elements (which is exactly what happened here)?

Comment: `find_all` returned more than 3 values.

Comment: You expect 3 elements but the result might contain less or more than 3 (according to the error message, more to be exact). Might want to set to a variable and do different things according to its length.

Comment: Can you show us the output of ```body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td')```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-c31034287e3f> in <module>                                                     
        2 
        3 row_number = 2
----> 4  d1, d2, d3 = body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: `find_all` returns a list that can contain any number of elements, in your case it is 4 or more, if you want to use assignment unpacking, please check the length of the array first using `len`

Comment: What does `len(body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td'))` return?

Comment: I was learning the example from: Beginning-Data-Science-with-Python-and-Jupyter-master book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td')` is more than three or less than three. So it is unable to assign it to `d1`, `d2`, `d3`

Comment: Can you show us the output of ```body_content.find_all('tr')[row_number].find_all('td')```?

Comment: thanks, it was d[1,..6].not three d. the book showed a wrong way

Comment: @ Vaibhav Jadhav  to mark as an answer, i think i need to provide the website i am scraping, etc contents... idea of yours gave me a way to the answer. thnx